# audio and video recording errors in android

Tags: android, video-capture, audio-recording

I need to record audio and video files to the 3gp/mp4 format in the same file and at the same time.
When I run, my application file is created with `videofile.3gp` but the video does not record to the SD card on the emulator.  Does video record on the emulator?  If I  run this code on an android supported device will I see these errors?

Code and errors below:

```
    package com.video;
/*
 * 
 * @copy Rights
 * audio.java
 * sample code for Eminosoft Developerworks Article
 * Android developent Team
 * www.eminosoft.cm
 * 
 */


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class video extends Activity {

    public MediaRecorder mrec = null;
    private Button startRecording = null;
    private Button stopRecording = null;
    private static final String TAG = "SoundRecordingDemo";
    File audiofile;
    File video;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mrec = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        Log.i(TAG , "Video starting");
        startRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startrecording);
        stopRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stoprecording);
        startRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
           try
           {    
               mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
               Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
               startRecording.setEnabled(false);
               stopRecording.setEnabled(true);
               stopRecording.requestFocus();
               startRecording();
           }catch (Exception ee)
           {
               Log.e(TAG,"Caught io exception " + ee.getMessage());
           }

          }
        });

        stopRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
              startRecording.setEnabled(true);
              stopRecording.setEnabled(false);
              startRecording.requestFocus();
              stopRecording();
              processaudiofile();
          }

        });

       stopRecording.setEnabled(false);
       startRecording.setEnabled(true);

    }
    protected void processaudiofile() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "video"+video.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int)(current/1000));
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/3gpp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, video.getAbsolutePath());
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri base=MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);
       // this does not always seem to work cleanly....
        //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,newUri ));
      }

    protected void startRecording() throws IOException 
    {

        // Configure the input sources
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Set the output format
        mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mrec.setVideoFrameRate(15);

        // Specify the audio and video encoding        
        mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

        //mrec.setMaxDuration(20000); // length of video in MS
        //mrec.setVideoSize(320, 240);


        // Specify the output file
        //mrec.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myoutputfile.mp4");

        // Prepare to record
        //mrec.prepare();

        //mrec.start();

      //mrec.setOutputFile(video.getPath());
      //mrec.setOutputFile(/sdcard/yousuck2.3gp);
     // mRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/yousuck2.3gp");
    if (video == null) {
              File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            try { 
                  video = File.createTempFile("videofile", ".3gp", sampleDir);
              } 
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                  Log.e(TAG,"sdcard access error");
                  return;
              }
      }

     mrec.setOutputFile(video.getAbsolutePath());

      mrec.prepare();
      mrec.start();
    }

    protected void stopRecording() {
        mrec.stop();
        mrec.release();
      }

}
```

I get the following errors.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16055): ERROR: thread attach failed

ERROR/audio_input(31): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value

ERROR/audio_input(31): VerifyAndSetParameter failed



 ERROR/CameraInput(31): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)


 ERROR/CameraInput(31): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0


 ERROR/PVOMXEncNode(31): PVMFOMXEncNode-Audio_AMRNB::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.PV.amrencnb handle 


 ERROR/PVOMXEncNode(31): PVMFOMXEncNode-Video_AVC::DoPrepare(): Cannot get component OMX.PV.avcenc handle, try another component if available



 ERROR/MediaPlayerService(31):   error: -2


 ERROR/MediaPlayer(31): Unable to to create media player



 ERROR/CameraService(31): Failed to load CameraService sounds.


 ERROR/MediaPlayerService(31):   error: -2

    ERROR/MediaPlayer(31): Unable to to create media player

 ERROR/CameraService(31): Failed to load CameraService sounds.

     ERROR/CameraInput(31): No surface is available for display.

 ERROR/AuthorDriver(31): Command 13 completed with error -1

 ERROR/SoundRecordingDemo(15961): Caught io exception prepare failed.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The camera API appears to require that many of the sources are set, including the audio, video, and preview surface.  The following code is more complete:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(previewSurface); 

recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT); 
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT); 

recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP); 

recorder.setMaxDuration(1000 * 10); 
recorder.setOnInfoListener(self); 

recorder.setVideoSize(200, 200); 
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);

recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/test.mp4");

recorder.prepare(); 
recorder.start();
```

Comment: Also, remember to set your permissions in the manifest to allow sound recording, camera, and external file storage.

Plus, here is another StackOverflow question that describes the recording setup (with surface) in more detail.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225763/record-video-to-external-sd-card-on-android

Comment: videoSize should be one of the supportedVideoSizes array. Otherwise the app will crash.

Comment: I'm doing this in a fragment, would you know how to setup a previewSurface?

Answer (score 0):

media record requires some H/W feature, such as video encoder(h264, h263)... emulator may not support. just try on your real device