# Android 2.1 camera preview error

Tags: camera, media-player, android

I have a problem with using the camera of an Android 2.1 phone (HTC Desire), maybe you can help me.
After calling camera.open() DDMS in Eclipse shows the following errors:

```
ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30):   error: -2
ERROR/MediaPlayer(30): Unable to to create media player
ERROR/CameraService(30): Failed to load CameraService sounds.
```

Test view in the emulator works fine, but on my phone only a popup is shown where I only can close the application.

Comment: Did you check this post out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281549/audio-and-video-recording-erros-in-android

Comment: I did, thx for the info. Now the errors in DDMS are gone but the emulator still crashes.