# Video recording format(.3gp or mp4) in android?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-camera

I use the `Intent` `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` video recording method.

By default, the recorded video is stored as a `.3gp` file. I want to record and store the video as a `.mp4` file.

Is this possible?.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes

Set the `MediaRecorder`'s `OutputFormat` to `MPEG_4`, like so:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
```

*This other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286938/293280) describes it perfectly, as well.*

Comment: This is assuming you're using the MediaRecorder directly. Karthi seems to be using an Intent.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk You're right, Josh. To use the `OutputFormat` you'll need to work with the `MediaRecorder()` directly. Using an `Intent`, could you not just pass the `.mp4` file extension in the `putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(temp_file_with_mp4_extension));`?

Comment: Does the MediaRecorder infer the video format from the file extension? I was unaware of this.

Answer (score 3):

[Yes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html), you can have an mp4 output format, mp4 is just a container : see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) to know what kind of data streams you can store in it.

```
MPEG_4  MPEG4 media file format
```

[Also refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281549/audio-and-video-recording-erros-in-android)

Comment: recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

Comment: i have record it and play directly in phone but i got black screen

Comment: Try playing the file on your PC, also I'll need to see the LogCat output to know what went wrong.

Comment: i have tryed in pc and working fine.but how can i play it in android device?