# Set video format for native camera application

Tags: android, video, camera

Is it possible to set file Format and encoder format for video while using native camera via Intent with flag ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE?

Comment: So is it not possible? If not then is there a way to provide the same video file format and codec format for all devices using native camera?

Comment: It is possible, and quite easy. I added an answer to describe how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video recording format(.3gp or mp4) in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026207/video-recording-format-3gp-or-mp4-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

Set the `MediaRecorder`'s `OutputFormat` to `MPEG_4`, like so:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
```

*This other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286938/293280) describes it perfectly, as well.*